# How to get desired response the way https://doesthisgifcontainananimation.com requests it?

Tags: html, json, get, request, animated-gif

Here's what site says and I just don't get it:

[image]

When accessing site with something like, for example:

```
https://doesthisgifcontainananimation.com/[URL http://i.imgur.com/tYqyhJT.gif URL]
```

all I get is just

{"error":"url_parsing_failed"}

I plan to use this along with a custom RSS feed in PHP to show entries classified regarding its content and in this case, also considering image type (Animated and non animated GIF's).

Any word of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although I'm still unclear about what you are asking, I'm positive that this is not a programming question

Comment: Apart from that, the page seems to be working fine for me (just encode the gif url)

Comment: I wasn't understanding that encoding part, but now that you reiterated it, I tried what you said. I was just believing that browser were always doing this for me (or at least it surely does with another U.R.L.'s).

Sorry I didn't explain my reasons early. I plan to this along with yahoo pipes, which I hope it may be enough to be considered as a programming question. But, anyway: now that my understanding is clear and problem solved you may proceed doing whatever you want with this question that now I recognize it was dumb. Or tell me just to do what I must.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, my apologies if I sounded harsh, it was not my intention. There are no dumb questions (although some people may disagree :P), but there are questions that are on and off-topic. You could close the question or answer it yourself so if somebody finds the same issue as you do, they can find a solution here.

Comment: No need to apologize. Answering and closing then...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FtYqyhJT.gif
```

Encoding means replacing slashes, colons and every single character on the URL that makes it being treated like an address, using their hex values preceded with a percent character, making it merely a parameter. The Full URL then is:

```
https://doesthisgifcontainananimation.com/http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FtYqyhJT.gif
```

The browser doesn't make this for you...at least not in this case.

Apologies for being dumb(er) at the beginning. All I can say now is that

```
https://doesthisgifcontainananimation.com/[URL encoded gif URL]
```

is as unclear as my past problem.

php code I used then is

```
$url="http://i.imgur.com/tYqyhJT.gif";
$encoded="https://doesthisgifcontainananimation.com/".urlencode($url);
```

And about encoding, [more information here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)